# Using jquery submit() causes function to be fired many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm writing some form validation code in jQuery. I've noticed something very strange with the following code:

```
var $form = $('#test-form');

$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    validate();
}); 

function validate() {
    console.log('in');
    $form.submit();
}
```

I expected to get the console.log back once and then for the form to submit. Instead I get the console log around 700 times and the form does not submit. This can be seen in this test:

http://jsfiddle.net/kZMf8/1/

What the hell is going on here?

Comment: You have a loop inside your code

Comment: Ah yes...of course. can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use native submit to bypass the jQuery event handler:

```
function validate() {
    console.log('in');
    $form.get(0).submit(); // same as document.getElementById("test-form").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a infinite loop inside your code:

```
var $form = $('#test-form');

$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();/*Prevent form validation default event*/
    validate();/*Call the function Validate*/
}); 

function validate() {
    console.log('in');/*Log in the console*/
    $form.submit();/*Call the default submit event of the form which get you back at line 4, this will go on fore ever.*/
}
```

you should avoid `$form.submit()` inside `validate()` as it will cause an infinite loop. `validate()` should use the data that the validation return not resubmit the form.

you probably are looking for something like :

```
function AJAXValidation()
{
    var request = $.ajax(
    {
        url: "Process.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        data:
        {
            /*your data*/
        }
    });

    /*call back fonction which is like your validate() function*/
    request.done(
        function(message)
        {
        /*Do stuff with message*/
        });
}
```

in this code message could be anything a JSON string, a name, a date, wahtever Process return.

Comment: No I'm not looking for ajax validation at all, I just needed to defer the submission of the form until I've done some validation on fields. It was a schoolboy error that I didn't spot the loop i'd created